# how to display the actual size of the picture in post

Tags: posts, images

I'm a beginner WordPress user and I have an issue on my site, the pictures in a post that I'm adding are displayed not in the actual size, but adjusted to the max page width. Attaching the picture as an example. Any tips and tricks on how to solve it?

How it looks like:

[image]

How I want to display the picture:

[image]

Thank you in advance!